# Retrive the (index,column) tuple of non nan values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,6,np.nan]])
```

The function should return me the array of tuples:

```
 [(0,0), (2,1)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the numpy functions `isnan` and `where`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,6,np.nan]])
>>> np.where(~np.isnan(df))
(array([0, 2]), array([0, 1]))
```

To obtain the data in the exact way as shown:

```
>>> inds = np.where(~np.isnan(df))
>>> zip(*inds)
[(0, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Using pandas built in functions you would have to apply `notnull()` over all series and then call a numpy function to the DataFrame anyway.

Edit: Apparently pandas has a `notnull` function for DataFrames in 0.13, you can replace all `~np.isnan(df)` with `df.notnull()` if you wish.